# dr.Item("Value1") has value but always return 0 when assigned to another variable

Tags: vb.net

I need to modify some VB.net code. There is a strange problem that I am facing. I am retrieving value from a DataTable and trying to assign it to a variable. When I check the value of some column in QuickWatch window then it has value but when I assign it to a variable then 0 is returned to the variable. Below is the simple statement that is causing the problem.

```
Dim MyAmount As Double = Double.Parse(dr.Item("Amount").ToString)
```

In the QuickWatch window when I check dr.Item("Amount") then it has value 30.12 and after executing the above statement MyAmount has value 0. May be VB.net work somewhat different that I do not know?

Edit:
It is kind of wierd that above mentioned statement is not returning value. The following statement is running absolutely fine.

```
Dim tmpVar As String() = dr.Item("Amount").ToString.Split(".")
```

Latest Edit:

I think it has become more wierd. The problem does not seem to be related with dr.Item("Amount"). Suppose I want to store the current culture value in a variable by following code,

```
Dim CultureInformation As String = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DisplayName
```

Now CutlureInformation variable after the statement is executed contains "nothing" but the DisplayName has value of English (United States). So I think the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: can I ask what culture you're working with please? e.g. "en-US", "fr-FR".

Comment: current culture is "en-US".

Comment: Could you refactor it to put `dr.Item("Amount").ToString` into another variable first and examine that? Just to make sure nothing peculiar is happening. Which version of VS are you using?

Comment: Framework 2.0. Visual Studio 2005 Professional. I have not written the code as I am no expert in VB.net, instead I am trying to modify some functionality. The site is hosted locally on IIS 7 and I am debugging it by attaching process to w3wp.exe and as I mentioned in the original posting that when I QuickWatch dr.Item("Amount") or move the pointer on it the value stored in it is displayed which is 30.12 but it is not assigning value to a variable.

Comment: I think it has become more wierd. The problem does not seem to be related with dr.Item("Amount"). Suppose I want to store the current culture value in a variable by following code,
Dim CultureInformation As String = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DisplayName

Now CutlureInformation variable after the statement is executed contains "nothing" but the DisplayName has value of English (United States). So I think the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: The `dr("Item").ToString` code follows a pattern I've seen from time to time for dealing with DbNull values, and I encourage you to re-write this to handle them better. Most likely, your `dr("Item")` expressions is **already** a double. You're converting to a string, just to convert it back to double again. This is very wasteful, resulting in slow and in-accurate data layer code.

Comment: Also, a value like `30.12` makes me suspect you're dealing with dollar amounts. If this is true, you should **not** be using the `Double` type at all, but rather the `Decimal` type to avoid IEEE754 rounding issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using this syntax:

```
Dim MyAmount As Double = dr.Field(Of Double)("Amount")
```

I am not sure why you are getting this behavior - your line should work too.

You can also try this:

```
Dim MyAmount As Double = DirectCast(dr.Item("Amount"), Double)
```

When facing a weird issue like this, always try various options to achieve the same result, do your research and compare the outputs. It greatly helps to answer a question on StackOverflow.

Comment: I am using framework 2.0. I am getting error "Field" is not member of System.Data.DataRow".

Comment: @AdnanYaseen: [dr.Field(Of T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.field(v=vs.90).aspx) is available in .NET 3.5+. Is there any reason why you cannot upgrade your project to at least .NET 4? If you have a **good** reason not to do it, you can try the other option I mentioned - it should work in .NET 2.0.

Comment: Frankly I would prefer to upgrade the project but as it is a  already running application not owned by me and it is beyond my current scope as I am just modifying some existing functionality. Kindly see my edited question.

Comment: @AdnanYaseen: You need at least VS 2008 to support applications in .NET 3.5. I would highly recommend you to upgrade at the earliest convenience. Regarding your update, if this works `dr.Item("Amount").ToString.Split(".")`, then you should also try this `Double.Parse("30,12")` and see how it performs. Or just parse a whole value. If it works, it's about your culture config, you can check here `Region and Language -> Additional settings... -> Decimal Symbol` (Windows 7).

Comment: I don't know how to explain this but I have now tested following lines of code and none of them work.
Dim CultureInformation As String = "Test"
Dim NewBid As Double = Double.Parse("30,12")

What more frustrating is that I am passing these values to a method along with an enumeration and only the enumeration value is being passed. I have even passed DirectCast(dr.Item("Amount"), Double) to the method directly without assigning it to a variable but it the value received in the method is nothing (for string), (0 for Double) and (7 for Enumeration). Like I said enumeration worked fine.

Comment: Is this some kind of Bug or some issue related to application while debugging it through IIS. I remember I had to attach the w3wp.exe process for debugging and breakpoint were not hit so I had to manually load the symbols. Are they causing this? What seem to be a simple variable issue at start turned out to be problem with every variable.

Comment: @AdnanYaseen: Rebuild the application and redeploy using debug build. Enable debugging, then you should not need to load symbols manually. They will be picked up automatically when you attach to process. Sometimes second attach to process is needed - it is okay, just try the 2nd time. Please update your question with this new information. Aside from nice alignment and syntax highlight, it may help future readers.

Comment: Same old error nothing changed. I have deleted the project dll file from bin folder. Clean the solution. Re-Build the solution. Restarted the application in IIS (Just in case). Debugged the application again but variable are still null. The benefit by doing all this is that I don't have to include the symbol everytime. I will try to investigate it a bit more and will update here if I got any success. In the meantime If you have any more suggestion then do tell me.

Comment: @AdnanYaseen: inspect this value in debugger `dr.Item("Amount").ToString` (if I understand it correctly, should be equal to `30.12`), then create a brand new web application which would `Double.Parse(THIS_VALUE)` and output via `Response.Write` in its only page. Or just assign into a variable, and go through it with a debugger. This way you should be able to isolate the problem, i.e. whether it's specific to your application or not.

Comment: I have created a new application and printed the line as you have mentioned. All ran well. I think the problem is application specific.

Comment: @AdnanYaseen: Then I believe there isn't much we can help with. Try to copy/paste parts of the application - see if it has any effect. Take special care with app.config.

Comment: You guys here already has done a lot and guided me through different steps. Solving a problem actually need to identify it first and I think now I am closer to solve the problem with the help of you and other respectable members.

Comment: @AdnanYaseen: You are welcome! Please don't forget to accept/upvote my answer, to mark it as helpful.